# Facebook Open Graph API - localization

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, localization

I have added this to my web page header

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_CA" />
```

However, no matter what I do, this

```
 $possibleLangValues = array(
    @$_REQUEST[ 'lang' ],
    @$_SERVER[ 'HTTP_X_FACEBOOK_LOCALE' ],
    @$_REQUEST[ 'fb_locale' ],
    @$_REQUEST[ 'fb_ref' ],
    @$_REQUEST[ 'locale' ],
);
```

leads to en empty array if I put my web page into the FB post or if I use developer debugger from Facebook. Anyone know, what to do?

Comment: remove the @ symbols and check for errors, should there be any.

Comment: @Fred-ii- this is there to overcome "notset", because all variables may not be set even if FB headers are sent correctly

Comment: This works for Open Graph stories only, not for normal URL shares.